# cordova-splash not working with getting an unhandled error event

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen

### when i run cordova-splash command this error to come.Getting an unhandled error event

```
    > 
    >     $ cordova-splash
    >     
    >     Checking Project & Splash
    >     
    >      ✓  platforms found: android
    >      ✓  splash.png exists
    >      ✓  config.xml exists
    >     
    >     Generating splash screen for Android
    >     
    >     events.js:85
    >          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    >                ^
    >   Error: spawn ENOENT
        at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Comment: Needed to install imagemagick. try and let me know.

Comment: Yes ! Needed to install imagemagick. Problem solved ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think You had some old splash screen configurations in config.xml. These were pointing to non-existent directories.so try to remove the old splash screen config lines, which probably will have fixed it. also try to close your terminal window and then reopen it after installing any module. (as @Furqan mentioned the imagemagick module which you probably missing).

Comment: yup @abdulhameed am still using previous window. after reopening it solved the issue.